# Using JQuery in angular asp.net core application

Tags: jquery, angular, webpack, asp.net-core

I am trying to use bootstrap methods in a custom directive in an asp.net core angular web application.  However, when I run the application, I get the error message "'jQuery' is undefined" in main-client.js.

If I change webpack.config.js to add the webPack.ProvidePlugin plugin, the problem goes away.

```
module.exports = (env) => {
    ...
    const sharedConfig = {        
        plugins: [
            new webpack.ProvidePlugin({ $: 'jquery', jQuery: 'jquery' }), // Maps these identifiers to the jQuery package (because Bootstrap expects it to be a global variable)
            new CheckerPlugin()
        ]
    };
    ...
};
```

However, this plugin already exists in webpack.config.vendor.js.  Why do I need to add it again?

Comment: Have you ever found a solution for this? I'm using the latest version of the dotnet core angular template

Answer (score 0):

Hello you can add this loader :

```
    /**
     * Special loading issue. to expose something as window.something in browser side.
     *
     * Reference : https://github.com/webpack-contrib/expose-loader
     */
    { test: require.resolve("jquery"), loader: "expose-loader?$!expose-loader?jQuery" }
```